# play-authenticate gives redirection error (Twitter Login)

Tags: java, twitter, playframework-2.0, play-authenticate

I am using play-authenticate to implement login with twitter on my web application. 
I have created an app on twitter. when the user clicks on the twitter link on my app, the user is redirected to the twitter where he provides his twitter credentials
while redirecting the user back to my app after successful login (via twitter) I get the following error

```
[NullPointerException: null]

In C:\live-events\eventify\target\scala-2.9.1\src_managed\main\routes_routing.scala .

case com_feth_play_module_pa_controllers_Authenticate_authenticate7(params) => {
   call(params.fromPath[String]("provider", None)) { (provider) =>invokeHandler(_root_.com.feth.play.module.pa.controllers.Authenticate.authenticate(provider), HandlerDef(this, "com.feth.play.module.pa.controllers.Authenticate", "authenticate", Seq(classOf[String])))
 }
}
```

(I provided the index page of my application as redirect URL and I am working on localhost so my RedirectURL is as follows)

```
 http://127.0.0.1:9000
```

Anyone have any idea about this error?

Thanks

Comment: It is probably not the cause of the error but have you tryied to use your external IP when defining the call back to your index-site?
I usualy create an account on changeip.com or a similar page to get a "real" URL even rather than using my external one.

Comment: You mean there is something wrong with my call back URL ? How can I configure it ?

Comment: I unfortunately dont know how you configure it (since i dont have any know-how of twitter, playframework, play-authenticate). Normaly this is either done on the call/redirect to the 3th party servcie or on an account on said 3th party service. I dont even know if this is your issue (dont think so regarding the NullPointerException) but thats what i would try first since one day that call-back needs to work with any URL rather than just your localhost.

Comment: yeah but its just a project for course, so I dont want to buy a real domain for it. I will prefer to work on localhost

Comment: Absolutly clear right there ;) On changeip.com for example you dont need to pay anything (your URL will look stupid and is a subdomain of changeip.com but it is a real URL and thatfore gets populated to the DNS Network as well). How i said i am not sure if this is your problem but i remember having had troubles when i added a PayPal-Pay function to a small website i had to configure the callback URL on a PayPal site and not just on the call to paypal. They havent accepted any URLs with IPs in them. Thats what lead me to the assumptation your problem could have similar roots ;)

Comment: Do you know where the NullPointerException is coming from? Which object is null?